# Retrieving multiple selection of a ListBox

Tags: c#

I have a ListBox that contains some names from a database query.

How can I retrieve these names when selecting multiple items?

Comment: Windows? Mac? iPhone? Android? Web? ... `C#` is used in so many environments, please specify in the tags what platform are you using... and if you are talking in Database, what ORM are you using.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample code see it

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        String strItem;
        foreach(Object selecteditem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            strItem = selecteditem as String;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strItem);
            //Process(strItem);
        }
    }
```